# Meaning of Clo(A), Int(A), Rint(A)

Tags: notation

I've just stumbled upon this notation in a text about optimalisation with no explanation as to what they mean (suggesting they are widely used and well known?). $A$ is a set (a convex set in this case) and the notation I am not sure of is: $$clo(A), int(A), rint(A)$$

I only need to know the names, as attempting to google these yielded no results. Thanks!

edit: I just found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology) so that's probably one of them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not widely used, so that is a BAD text for not defining them.  My guess: Clo = closure, Int = interior, Rint = relative interior.  (Also it is a bad text if it uses the word *optimalisation* instead of *optimisation*.)

Comment: Thanks! Well the text is in Czech and optimalisation is my translation, so that would be mistake on my part, but as for the usage of those terms, you're right!

Comment: Actually, thinking about it - why is optimalisation bad?